# MySQL SELECT sum of a column, GROUP BY date failing when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled

Tags: mysql, sql

**My Query:**

```
SELECT      portfolio_id, 
            sum(shares_owned_value_usd) as sum_shares_owned_value_usd, 
            date_utc, 
            sum(dividends_received_value_usd) as total_dividends_received_usd,
            (sum(dividends_received_value_usd) over (order by date_utc range between interval 1 year preceding and current row)) as dividends_usd_ttm
FROM        stock_portfolio_historical_values
WHERE       portfolio_id = 5
GROUP BY    date_utc
ORDER BY    date_utc ASC
```

**Error:**

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'stock_portfolio_historical_values' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

My table `stock_portfolio_historical_values` has a primary key named `id`, if this is needed to fix my query.

**My Schema:**

| id | portfolio_id | ticker | shares_owned_value_usd | dividends_received_value_usd | date_utc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 5 | AAPL | 300 | 15 | 2022-06-08 |
| 499 | 5 | MSFT | 1000 | 30 | 2022-06-08 |
| 498 | 5 | AAPL | 200 | 0 | 2022-06-07 |
| 497 | 5 | MSFT | 900 | 0 | 2022-06-07 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 403 | 5 | AAPL | 300 | 15 | 2022-03-05 |
| 402 | 5 | MSFT | 1000 | 30 | 2022-03-05 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 102 | 5 | AAPL | 300 | 10 | 2021-03-05 |
| 101 | 5 | MSFT | 1000 | 15 | 2021-03-05 |

**Expected Results:**

| portfolio_id | sum_shares_owned_value_usd | total_dividends_received_usd | dividends_usd_ttm | date_utc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1300 | 45 | 90 | 2022-06-08 |
| 5 | 1100 | 0 | 45 | 2022-06-07 |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . |

**Note:** This query works fine with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled, but I am trying to get it to work with it enabled.

Comment: Exclude `portfolio_id` from the output list.

Comment: @Akina Still getting a similar error with that change `Expression #4 of SELECT is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column dividends_received_value_usd`

Answer (score 1):

One option is separating the aggregation from the windowing operation, then join back the two results:

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT SUM(shares_owned_value_usd)        AS sum_shares_owned_value_usd,
              SUM(dividends_received_value_usd)  AS total_dividends_received_usd,
              date_utc 
       FROM stock_portfolio_historical_values
       WHERE portfolio_id = 5
       GROUP BY date_utc
)
SELECT SUM(dividends_received_value_usd) OVER(
              ORDER BY date_utc 
              RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 1 YEAR PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS dividends_usd_ttm,
       stock.date_utc
FROM      cte 
LEFT JOIN stock_portfolio_historical_values stock
      AND stock.date_utc     = cte.date_utc 
      AND stock.portfolio_id = 5
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'date_utc' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Yeah I missed the table name, try using `stock.date_utc` in the query. Just updated the query.

Comment: Thanks -- first I got an error about missing `portfolio_id` but I added that to the `cte` query (`... date_utc, portfolio_id FROM stock_portfolio_historical_values...`), and now I'm getting this new error: `Invalid parameter number` EDIT: Actually this is on my end I'm pretty sure, checking now

Comment: I've removed the condition inside the ON clause on portfolios, given that I'm filtering in both query and cte where portfolio = 5. Try now @HC_